# Laravel replace null with default values

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent

I've been struggling with something I would have expected to be a very simple task in Laravel.

Basically, I have a table with multiple columns with default values, to allow user to leave certain fields empty instead of having to write "0" everywhere. This is how my migration looks for reference:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id()->autoIncrement();
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->date('arrival_date');
        $table->date('departure_date');
        $table->smallInteger('sector')->nullable();
        $table->smallInteger('adults')->default('0');
        $table->smallInteger('children')->default('0');
        $table->smallInteger('electricity')->default('0');
        $table->smallInteger('small_places')->default('0');
        $table->smallInteger('big_places')->default('0');
        $table->smallInteger('discount')->default('0');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

The problem is - I can't seem to find a way to use default values - sending a form with empty fields puts them as "null" values, which are still treated as values, so attempting to create the model ends up with errors about null values. Neither default values in DB work, nor default model values - as each of these gets overwritten. Default model values for reference:

```
protected $attributes = [
    'adults' => 0,
    'children' => 0,
    'electricity' => 0,
    'small_places' => 0,
    'big_places' => 0,
    'discount' => 0
];
```

So far I found a few solutions, none of which feels right, I feel like I'm missing something.

So, my current solution looks like this:

```
public static function add(Request $request)
{
    if (!self::validateRequest($request)) return; // Just checks if required fields are OK, doesn't change values
    Client::create(array_filter($request->all(), function ($item) {
        return !empty($item);
    }));
}
```

Basically, I just remove all "null" values from $request, so default ones from the DB are used instead. The downside to this solution, is when I would actually WANT to assign a null value - it would get removed.

The second solution I found would work well but adds a ton of code and would have to be made specifically for any Model. I could make a middleware / just a function in my model, that has a list of nullable keys and default values, and if a key is null and is not nullable it would replace it with default value.
The thing with this solution is that... I'm basically writing rules that are already in the database but again. This would make nullables and default values in my database redundant, as I already do everything in my code...

So - is there no way to, for example, use already written Migration as a template for validation or something like this, or is there anything in Laravel made to solve this specific problem? If not, is there any better way to go about it than I did?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use mutators in the Model.`public function setAdultsAttribute($value) { ... }` as described in https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

Comment: 0 is considered as null. Try to put other value than 0 or 1. Then see what's the result.

Comment: I tried using 1 as well and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I'll try out mutators, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is something that I do not understand. You want the empty fields to be 0 by default so that users do not put 0 in all but you want them to have the possibility of putting null fields. How could they make a field null? Maybe it would be easier to add `value="0"` in the inputs.

Comment: I want only certain fields to be 0, like I set for the database. first_name and last_name can be null for example, so removing them because of null breaks things. value="0" is one way to go about it but if someone deletes the value things will break.